# DisclosurePanel styling bug?

Tags: gwt, uibinder

Here is my problem: When I navigate to the view shown below, the disclosurepanel has a big distance to the grid and when I click on a disclosurepanel header it gets a "selection border" - But when I refresh the browser, everything is on the position where it should be and the disclosurepanel header doesnt get selected anymore when I click on it.
I have a ui.xml like this:

```
<g:HTMLPanel>
    <g:VerticalPanel>
        <g:Grid>
            <g:row>
                <g:customCell>
                    <g:Button ui:field="editBTN" width="50px"></g:Button>
                </g:customCell>
                <g:customCell>
                    <g:Button ui:field="deleteBTN" width="50px"></g:Button>
                </g:customCell>
                <g:customCell>
                    <g:Label ui:field="date" width="100px"></g:Label>
                </g:customCell>
                <g:customCell>
                    <g:Label ui:field="begin" width="100px"></g:Label>
                </g:customCell>
                <g:customCell>
                    <g:Label ui:field="end" width="100px"></g:Label>
                </g:customCell>
                <g:customCell>
                    <g:Label ui:field="pause" width="100px"></g:Label>
                </g:customCell>
                <g:customCell>
                    <g:Label ui:field="sum" width="100px"></g:Label>
                </g:customCell>
                <g:customCell>
                    <g:Label ui:field="tasks" width="100px"></g:Label>
                </g:customCell>
            </g:row>
        </g:Grid>       


            <g:DisclosurePanel>
                <g:header>test</g:header>
            </g:DisclosurePanel>
            <g:DisclosurePanel>
                <g:header>test</g:header>
                <g:Grid>
                <g:row>
                    <g:customCell>
                        <g:TextBox ui:field="fromDATEtbx" width="100px"></g:TextBox>
                    </g:customCell>
                    <g:customCell>
                        <g:TextBox ui:field="toDATEtbx" width="100px"></g:TextBox>
                    </g:customCell>
                </g:row>
            </g:Grid>       
            </g:DisclosurePanel>
    </g:VerticalPanel>
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

Is this a known bug/mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok solved the Problem. 
Somehow it adds

`td {
    padding: 8px;
}`

to your styling. I simply set

`td {
    padding: 0px;
}`

to my uibinder.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed sometimes this "selection border" for my disclosure panels when was working in debug mode. Did not see this in production mode though.

If you really need to get rid of that effect by all means, you can try to set "`outline: none;`" to your `disclosurePanel.getHeader().getParent()` which will prevent showing the highlighted border (which is usually OK for active focused element in new browsers) for `<a href=...>` element that wraps the disclosure panel's header.

You may also check what is happening with that header in devtools, when you see the unexpected space between elements. And compare that to what you see after refresh. So you may notice the difference and then find out what causes that.

Comment: yea I tried to check what is happening in devtools but couldnt find a difference so far. Gonna try set the outline to none and check the devtools later again. I will let you know if it will work.